# Oracle DB 12c connection issue

Tags: oracle12c

I am facing an Oracle DB 12c connection issue with the error mentioned below.

> ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in
>   connect descriptor

Screen shot showing the error message posted below.

[image]

tnsnames.ora file content generated by Oracle configuration tools posted below.

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1588))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
)
)

PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You entered `ORADIM` into the `SID` item. There's no database called "ORADIM" in your TNSNAMES.ORA.

If I were you', I'd try with

- ORCL or
- PDBORCL

entered into **SERVICE_NAME**.

Comment: Nope i have tried all those things. still the same error when i enter in SERVICE_NAME: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor